# y value for `geom_label` in ggplot2 based on `..count..` variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, histogram, tidyverse

I want to create a histogram where there is a vertical line denoting the mean value and a label attached to this line that gives the exact value for the mean.

I can create the basic histogram with a vertical line easily.

```r
# needed library
library(ggplot2)

# mean to be used later
x_mean <- mean(x = iris$Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)

# creating basic plot with line for mean
(
  plot <- ggplot(data = iris,
                 mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
    stat_bin(
      col = "black",
      alpha = 0.7,
      na.rm = TRUE,
      mapping = aes(y = ..count..,
                    fill = ..count..)
    )  +
    geom_vline(
      xintercept = x_mean,
      linetype = "dashed",
      color = "red",
      na.rm = TRUE
    ) +
    scale_fill_gradient(name = "count",
                        low = "white",
                        high = "white") +
    guides(fill = FALSE)
)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Now I can add a label to this line using the following code:

```r
# adding label to the line
plot +
  geom_label(mapping = aes(
    label = list(bquote("mean" == ~ .(
      format(round(x_mean, 2), nsmall = 2)
    ))),
    x = x_mean,
    y = 5  # how to automate this value choice?
  ),
  parse = TRUE)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Now the problem here is that I am hard-coding the `y`-value for `geom_label` (`y = 5`). This is not ideal because if I change the data or the variable or the binwidth, `y = 5` will no longer be the (approximate) middle of the y-axis. I tried setting `y = max(..count..)/2`, but this results in the following error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'count' not found

To sum it up:
How can a choice of `y` value for `geom_label` in this context be automated so that no matter the range of counts, the label is always centered at the middle of the Y-axis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the current y-axis range from `plot`, by replacing the hard-coded `y = 5` in your code with `y = mean(layer_scales(plot)$y$range$range)`.

That way, if the parameters change, the change in scale is accounted for.

```
# layer_scales(plot) gives the scale information for plot
> layer_scales(plot)$y
`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
<ScaleContinuousPosition>
 Range:     0 --   12
 Limits:    0 --   12

# this is the actual vector for y-axis scale range
> layer_scales(plot)$y$range$range
`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
[1]  0 12

# this is the y-axis midpoint value
> mean(layer_scales(plot)$y$range$range)
`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
[1] 6
```